# Simplifying integral $\int_4^3 \sqrt{(x - 3)(4 - x)} dx$ by an easy approach

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

So I have this Integral $$\int_4^3 \sqrt{(x - 3)(4 - x)} dx$$

I know I can easily evaluate it using the by first converting it into this form $$\int \sqrt{a^2 + x^2} dx$$ and then using the direct formula for this.

But since this one's a definite integral and while evaluating it's getting very long and taking time to solve. Also the probability of committing a mistake is high. 
I was wondering if there's an easy approach to evaluate such integrals without doing this much maths.

This question appeared in my exam for for just 2 marks and it took me a long time to solve.  I don't think this much calculation is justified for just 2 marks.

Kindly help me with an easy approach.

Comment: I think try $x=3\sin^2\theta+4\cos^{2}\theta$

Comment: @Mann can you elaborate what you are trying to say? I didn't get any idea.

Comment: check now, i elaborated a bit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let $x=3.5+t$. We are finding $\int_{1/2}^{-1/2}\sqrt{(1/2)^2-t^2}\,dt$, which we recognize as (the negative of) a familiar area.

Comment: So the total area will be $0$ and so will the value of the integral. Correct me if I'm getting it wrong.

Comment: The integral (apart from the reversal of the limits) is the area of the top half of a circle of radius $1/2$. The full circle has area $\pi/4$, so the half-circle has area $\pi/8$, reversal of limits means the answer is $-\pi/8$.

Comment: got it sir. But now it seems fairly easy to but is there a reason why I didn't get it like you at my first glance. I mean I also knew this method but I couldn't think like you. While you got it within a few seconds.

Comment: @user109256:  The difference is that because of experience I recognized and exploited the **symmetry**.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I think we should perform a Turing test with you and hopefully conclude that you are indeed an A.I program haha

Comment: @MathFreak: On a more serious note, I think that something like the answer I gave is the default answer, it is what "everybody" would do.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Peut-être bien, mais j’acquiesce au fait que vous n'êtes probablement pas un automate en vertu de la manière dont vous venez de répondre à mon commentaire

Answer (score 2):

Here a elaboration.

Given integral is $\int_4^3 \sqrt{(x-3)(4-x)} \;\mathbb{d}x$

if $x=3\sin^2\theta+4\cos^2\theta$,
then integral is from $0\leq\theta\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$.

$\mathbb{d}x=(3\times 2\times sin\theta\times\cos\theta-4\times2\times\cos\theta\times\sin\theta)\mathbb{d}\theta$

$\mathbb{d}x=-2\sin\theta\cos\theta\;\mathbb{d}\theta$

$$I=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos\theta\times\sin\theta\times(-2\sin\theta\cos\theta)\mathbb{d}\theta$$

If you know beta function, it's a pretty straightforward integral but even if you don't, just use $2\sin\theta\cos\theta=\sin(2\theta)$

Comment: Loved that method. Sorry to bother you again I could have elaborated it too.

Answer (score 1):

A similar approach but without substitutions is to complete the square inside the radical to get
$$ \sqrt{-\left(x-\frac{7}{2}\right)^2 + \frac{1}{4}}. $$
Let $y$ equal this expression, square both sides, add $\left(x - \dfrac{7}{2}\right)^2$ to both sides.  Graph it.  What is it?  How does the integral relate to the graph?  (Be careful when answering that last question!)